# Comparison of dependent but unpaired data sets

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, mean, independence

I'm trying to find a statistical test that can help me compare the means of two dependent groups.

My data:

1. parameter values from white matter region in an in vivo rat brain
2. parameter values from white matter region in the same rat brain, bur after the tissue has been fixated.

I cannot align / register the two brains to each other, so the region I have outlined in vivo is not exactly the same as the region I have outlined in the fixated tissue.

My wish:

- I would like to compare the means of the two white matter regions.

My suggestion:

- A paired t-test, but as I know that each pixel value in data set 1 does not exactly correspond to the pixel value in data set 2, the paired t-test is not exactly right to do.

Is there a test of dependent but NOT paired data?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can compare values before and after fixation (whatever that is), which means a paired test. Your difficulty is scientific as well as statistical, in disentangling how far differences reflect the result of fixation and how far they reflect differences in what tissue has been outlined. The question is how far everyone in your field must have the same difficulty.

Comment: Hi Nick. Thank you for your answer. So the paired t-test is still the one to go with, but there is just a chance that the result will reflect the difference in choice of region in the two data sets?

Comment: That's what you implied!

Comment: Your values are pairwise dependent. This is still 'pairing' in the required statistical sense. Unless you can also measure the effect of the mismatch, your difficulty comes at the conclusion stage. (Yes, I am largely echoing what you already have. Sometimes it can be useful to hear it from more than once source.)